# Can we use the present continuous with a gerund, other than the specific examples listed?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Can we use the present continuous with a gerund in instances other than have been + present participle + gerund , am considering + gerund, and "am going to + gerund" ?

I've taken the following examples from ["Thinking About Using -ing Words?"](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-thinking-about-using-ing-words/4282670.html) at Learning English.

> verb + gerund One common situation in which two -ing words can appear
> next to each other is when the first -ing word is part of a continuous
> verb tense and the second -ing word is a gerund, as in the first
> example:
>
> I’ve been avoiding going to the doctor.
>
> Here, have been avoiding is the present perfect continuous form of to
> avoid. Going is the gerund.
>
> Here’s another example:
>
> I’m considering buying a home in DC.
>
> Here, am considering is the present continuous form of the verb to
> consider. Buying is the gerund.
>
> go + gerund Two -ing words can also appear together in what we call
> “go + gerund.” Go + gerund is an example of the verb + gerund
> construction.
>
> In English, we add the verb to go to certain recreational activities.
> These activities include fishing, swimming, shopping and skating, plus
> more than a dozen more.
>
> Because of this, when go is in the continuous verb tense, you will see
> two -ing words together.
>
> Listen:
>
> I’m going shopping in Alexandria next weekend.
>
> In this sentence, am going is the present continuous form of the verb
> to go and the gerund is shopping.
>
> Here’s another:
>
> We’re going skating on Friday in the sculpture garden.
>
> In this sentence, are going is the present continuous form of the verb
> to go and skating is the gerund.
>
> Note, however, that you will not see two -ing words together when go
> is not in the continuous tense with these activities. For example: “We
> went skating in the sculpture garden last Friday” is still part of the
> go + gerund structure.

Are there any other grammar constructions than these with a verb-ing + gerund?

Thanks!

Comment: I should mention that "I'm considering buying," one of the examples quoted, uses neither "have been + present participle + gerund" nor "am going to + gerund." So, that actually answers your question with "yes," without the need to provide anything else …

Comment: Yes oops , fixed question to show changes. I just want to know if there is a rule to this really, or a list of verbs somewhere ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!  A few moments ago, I was sitting enjoying a glass of whiskey, and began to wonder whether [sit] is a transitive verb and whether [enjoying a glass of whiskey] can function as its direct object.  A quick search brought me to your unanswered question.

I've now googled a variety of combinations of "[am/are/is/was] sitting [gerund]", and found many common usages, such as:  am sitting enjoying, am sitting drinking, am sitting eating, am sitting playing.

The verb [sit] is not listed as a catenative verb, but there are a variety of catenative verbs that would lead to the construction you are inquiring about.  For example, the catenative verb [advise] produces, "He is advising leaving now."  See this [list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs#Followed_by_a_gerund) of catenative verbs that license gerunds.

This process leads me to believe that at least one sense of the verb [sit] is a catenative that licenses gerunds.  Or, perhaps [sit] is not catenative, in which case, my gerund, [enjoying a glass of whiskey], in functioning as an [adjunct adverbial](https://parentingpatch.com/adjunct-adverbial-english-grammar/).  I'd appreciate comments on those possibilities.

In either case, my answer to your question is a definitive yes.